# Angularjs directive canceling out my form submits

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For some reason, the following directive is canceling my form submissions and I don't know why. Can anyone tell what is going on?

The reason for the `ngMobileClick` is so that the touchstart works nicely on the specific button that it's connected to.

```
.directive('ngMobileClick', function() {
    return function (scope, elem, attrs) {    
        function mobilecheck() {var check = false;(function(a) {if (/(android|ipad|playbook|silk|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(a) || /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0, 4))) {check = true;}})(navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera);return check;}

        var clickevent = mobilecheck() ? 'touchstart' : 'click';

        elem.bind(clickevent, function (e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            scope.$apply(attrs["ngMobileClick"]);
        });
    }
})
```

Below is the following code that I have:

```
<div id="button" ng-mobile-click="functionToRun()">Click me</div>

<form name="login_frm" ng-submit="login_frm.$valid && login()" novalidate>
    <input name="email" ng-model="email" type="email" placeholder="email address" value="" required />
    <input name="password" ng-model="password" type="password" placeholder="password" value="" required />
    <button name="submit" id="loginButton" type="submit">Log In</button>
</form>
```

Comment: How do you know it's this directive that cancels your submissions ? More, By canceling submissions you mean that when you click on the submit button, the form is not submitted ?

Comment: @Xartok I know it cancels the submission because nothing happens inside the `login()` function unless I comment out the directive. Correct, `login()` does not get run.

Comment: Can you show the code of functionToRun in this case ?

Comment: @Xartok It's irrelevant. just imagine it's empty or has a console log. The sole problem is in the directive

Comment: I've created a plunkr with the given code and it works http://plnkr.co/edit/ifp1anEKbAQwuIHshrEt The only way I see for login to not get run is that the form is invalid. And the only place it can be made invalid is in functionToRun to my mind.

Comment: @Xartok the functionToRun is not even inside the form.

Comment: functionToRun is attached to the same scope as the form. So it can modify it